# Как сместить вниз сразу два блока section вместо одного при уменьшении экрана

Tags: css3, html5

Здравствуйте! Помогите новичку решить такую проблему:

Делаю меню подразделов сайта на чистом html 5/css 3 без фреймворков.
В блоке nav - 4 блока  section со своим содержимым.

При уменьшении экрана блоки section смещаются вниз по-одному. То есть при ширине экрана, когда 4 блока в ряд не помещаются, вниз сдвигается последний (т.е. четвертый).

А мне нужно, чтобы смещались сразу 2 блока.  А то совсем криво получается, когда в первом ряду 3 блока, а во втором один.

Как мне сделать принудительный перенос именно двух блоков на этой ширине экрана?

Спасибо!

```css
   figure {
    background: #5f6a72; /* Цвет фона */
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг */
    display: inline-block; /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
    width: 150px; /* Ширина */
    height: 250px; /* Ширина */
    float: left; /* Блоки выстраиваются по горизонтали */
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /* Отступы */
    text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по центру */
   }
   figcaption {
display: block;
    color: #fff; /* Цвет текста */
   }
```

```html
<html><head></head>

<body>
<p>Для удобства выбора квартиры на нашем сайте сгруппированы по районам и станциям метро, по количеству комнат. Вы можете отдельно просматривать последние обновления. В отдельный раздел вынесены посуточные квартиры</p>


<nav>


<section class="choice">
<figure>
<h1><a href=''>Последнее обновление<a></h1>
<p><img src='pic1.jpg'alt='Все квартиры за сегодня'></p>
<figcaption>Адреса и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption>
</figure>
</section>

<section class="choice">
<figure>
<h1><a href=''>По районам СПб</a></h1>
<p><img src='pic1.jpg'alt='Квартиры по районам и метро'></p>
<br />
<figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам <br />и станциям метро</figcaption>
</figure>
</section>



<section class="choice">
<figure>
<h1><a href=''>Однокомнатные, двухкомнатные,<br /> 3ккв и более</a></h1>
<p><img src='pic2.jpg' alt='1ккв, 2ккв, 2ккв'></p>
<figcaption>База квартир <br />по количеству <br />комнат</figcaption>
</figure>
</section>


<section class="choice">
<figure>
<h1><a href=''>Посуточные квартиры</a></h1>
<p><img src='pic2.jpg' alt='Аренда на несколько дней'></p>
<figcaption><br />Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption>
</figure>
</section>


</nav>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
 figure {
     background: #5f6a72; /* Цвет фона */
     padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг */
     display: inline-block; /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
     width: 150px; /* Ширина */
     height: 250px;/* Ширина */
     float: left; /* Блоки выстраиваются по горизонтали */
     margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /* Отступы */
     text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по центру */
 }
 
 figcaption {
     display: block;
     color: #fff; /* Цвет текста */
 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
     .choice:nth-of-type(2n + 2) figure {
         float: none;
     }
 }
```

```html
<nav>


    <section class="choice">
        <figure>
            <h1><a href=''>Последнее обновление</a></h1>
            <p><img src='pic1.jpg' alt='Все квартиры за сегодня'></p>
            <figcaption>Адреса и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>

    <section class="choice">
        <figure>
            <h1><a href=''>По районам СПб</a></h1>
            <p><img src='pic1.jpg' alt='Квартиры по районам и метро'></p>
            <br />
            <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам
                <br />и станциям метро</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>



    <section class="choice">
        <figure>
            <h1><a href=''>Однокомнатные, двухкомнатные,<br /> 3ккв и более</a></h1>
            <p><img src='pic2.jpg' alt='1ккв, 2ккв, 2ккв'></p>
            <figcaption>База квартир
                <br />по количеству
                <br />комнат</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>


    <section class="choice">
        <figure>
            <h1><a href=''>Посуточные квартиры</a></h1>
            <p><img src='pic2.jpg' alt='Аренда на несколько дней'></p>
            <figcaption>
                <br />Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>


</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я уже думала про медиа-запросы. Но надеялась, что существует способ более изящный. Или, нет, неправильная формулировка. Искала способ проще и была уверена, что он есть, а я торможу :))

Comment: На самом деле очень изящно, да :)